# Given an open cover of $X$, $f:I \rightarrow X$, $\exists 0\leq s_1 ..\leq s_n = 1$ such that $f([s_i, s_{i+1}]) \subset A_\alpha$, $A_\alpha$ unique

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

The problem:

You are given a continuous function $f: [0,1] \rightarrow X$.

We choose an open cover of $X$, $A_{\alpha}$.

Then we want to show that there exists $0= s_1 \leq .... \leq s_n=1$ such that $f([s_i, s_{i+1}]) \subseteq A_k$, for an unique $A_k$ for all $i$.

This was from Hatcher, as can be seen here:

[image]

My Attempt:

First note that $f^{-1}(A_\alpha)$ is an open cover of $[0,1]$, so we may choose some finite subcover of $[0,1]$, $f^{-1}(A_1), ..... ,f^{-1}(A_n)$.

From Lebesgue's Number Lemma(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%27s_number_lemma), choose $\delta > 0$.

Note if $t,s \in [0,1]$, $t<s$ and $\left|t-s\right| < \delta$, by the lemma, $[t,s] \subseteq f^{-1}(A_i)$ for some $A_i$ in the cover. Hence, $f([t,s]) \subseteq A_i$.

So partition $[0,1]$ by the closed interval of length less than $\delta$. Then each image is mapped to a subset of $A_i$.

But my problem is that each closed interval needs to be mapped to a single or unique $A_i$. But from my proof, I cannot see the uniqueness part.

So if anyone could help with the uniqueness part, I would be grateful.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Maybe it just means that for all i there exists an A_k in the family such that f([s_i, s_i+1]) is entirely contained in A_k. To me the uniqueness requisite as you intended it seems strange. For example, if we choose A_alpha to be the family of all open subsets of X, it seems pretty desperate to pretend to have a unique A_k containing each section.

Comment: @GiacomMaletto, the text does say we can choose a closure contained in single $A_\alpha$. Is the single part needed if we don't care about uniqueness?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't have to worry about the uniqueness part, and that the author just wasn't very clear. In fact, I think it's false; consider this example.

Let $f:I \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be a loop at the base point $(0,0)$ and let $A_t$ be the family of half-planes $A_t = \{x < t\}\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ for $t > 0$. Then how can a section of the path belong to just one element only of the family?

Comment: I guess I misunderstood the "single" part. Thanks!

Comment: @Phil Indeed. The only thing that is needed and used is that there is some $A_\alpha$ that contains the whole $f[[s_i, s_{i+1}]]$.